# Apache refuses to start claiming a wrong PID

Tags: apache-httpd, raspberry-pi, init-script, sysvinit, buildroot

I'm facing an odd problem on a Buildroot environment for RPi3.
I have this init.d service to start `apache2` (version 2.4.57):

```
# cat /etc/init.d/S50apache 
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
  start|restart|graceful|graceful-stop|stop)
    apachectl -k $1
    ;;
  reload)
    apachectl -k restart
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|restart|reload|graceful|graceful-stop|stop}"
    exit 1
esac

exit $?
```

Often, when I power up the RPi3 I notice the web server is not running.
If I try to run the very same command, i.e.:

```
# apachectl -k start
```

I get:

```
httpd (pid 288) already running
```

but:

```
# ps aux | grep httpd
  477 root     grep httpd
```

and:

```
# ps aux | grep 288
  288 root     /usr/sbin/wpa_supplicant -u
  457 root     grep 288
```

It seems obvious (unless I'm missing something) that `apache2` is not running and the PID 288 is about a completely different service.

In order to start the webserver I have to:

1. `apachectl -k stop` -> this actually stops the `wpa_supplicant` service!
2. restart the `wpa_supplicant` service
3. now `apachectl -k start` works and the `apache2` service runs

Of course this is not acceptable. Furthermore, the machine will be unattended hence I need to fix this issue.

But I first have to understand why it happens. How is it possible it thinks it has a different PID?

Answer (score 1):

In older Apache servers, there was a bug

> stale apache PID files can prevent process from starting #3553

Check under `/var/run` if there is such a PID file and delete it.

And upgrade your Apache.

Comment: Could you add the version which had this bug? Mine is 2.4.57 and it's quite recent. The last seems 2.4.58 and in the [change log](http://archive.apache.org/dist/httpd/CHANGES_2.4.58) I don't see anything related.

Comment: Patch was released in 2018, so if your apache is recent, this bug should have been patched. Is there a stale PID?

Comment: I'll check next time it happens